# How to add multiple words in simple adapter android?

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete

I am building an android application where I am using AutoComplete text to show the search of google place name. Now the problem I am facing is if I enter space between 2 words, it stops displaying any results.

For Ex. - On writing the text "new" it will suggest me "new dehli", "new zealand" etc.,  when I use a space after the word "new", it stops displaying any result. I have tried couple of things along with:
- input = input.replaceAll(" ","%20");

After debugging, I checked that the results are coming but they are not adding in my simple list using adapter. But it looks like the simple list adapter is not adding the space character and there by not displaying the result.

Here is the code -

1. oncreateview -

   ```
   atvPlaces = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.atv_places);
   atvPlaces.setThreshold(1);      

   atvPlaces.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int 
       count) {                
           placesTask = new PlacesTask();              
           placesTask.execute(s.toString());
       }

       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
               int after) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
       }
   });

     /** A method to download json data from url */
     private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
     String data = "";
   InputStream iStream = null;
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
   try{
           URL url = new URL(strUrl);                

           // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
           urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

           // Connecting to url 
           urlConnection.connect();

           // Reading data from url 
           iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

           StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

           String line = "";
           while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                   sb.append(line);
           }

           data = sb.toString();

           br.close();

   }catch(Exception e){
           Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
   }finally{
           iStream.close();
           urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
   return data;
    }  

    // Fetches all places from GooglePlaces AutoComplete Web Service
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... place) {
       // For storing data from web service
       String data = "";

       // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
       String key = "key=AIzaSyC3qD9x9SbFGgK69xGtmyieAKaS0kMcpLE";

       String input="";



       try {
           input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place[0], "utf-8");
           input = input.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
       } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
           e1.printStackTrace();
       }       


       // place type to be searched
       String types = "types=geocode";

       // Sensor enabled
       String sensor = "sensor=false";         

       // Building the parameters to the web service
       String parameters = input+"&"+types+"&"+sensor+"&"+key;

       // Output format
       String output = "json";

       // Building the url to the web service
       String url = 

    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"+output+"?"+

     parameters;

       try{
           // Fetching the data from web service in background
           data = downloadUrl(url);
       }catch(Exception e){
           Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
       }
       return data;        
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
       super.onPostExecute(result);

       // Creating ParserTask
       parserTask = new ParserTask();

       // Starting Parsing the JSON string returned by Web Service
       parserTask.execute(result);
   }       
   }


    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
     private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, 
     List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

   JSONObject jObject;

   @Override
   protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String...   
   jsonData) {         

       List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;

       PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

       try{
           jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

           // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
           places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

       }catch(Exception e){
           Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
       }
       return places;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {            

           String[] from = new String[] { "description"};
           int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

           // Creating a SimpleAdapter for the AutoCompleteTextView            
           SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(),  
           result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);             

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), placesTask+"", 
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           // Setting the adapter
           atvPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);
   }           
   }
   ```

Here is placejson code -

```
public class PlaceJSONParser {

/**
 * Receives a JSONObject and returns a list
 */
public List<HashMap<String, String>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {

    JSONArray jPlaces = null;
    try {
        /** Retrieves all the elements in the 'places' array */
        jPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("predictions");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /** Invoking getPlaces with the array of json object
     * where each json object represent a place
     */
    return getPlaces(jPlaces);
}


private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jPlaces) {
    int placesCount = jPlaces.length();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> place = null;

    /** Taking each place, parses and adds to list object */
    for (int i = 0; i < placesCount; i++) {
        try {
            /** Call getPlace with place JSON object to parse the place */
            place = getPlace((JSONObject) jPlaces.get(i));
            placesList.add(place);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return placesList;
}

/**
 * Parsing the Place JSON object
 */
private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject jPlace) {

    HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String id = "";
    String reference = "";
    String description = "";

    try {

        description = jPlace.getString("description");
        id = jPlace.getString("id");
        reference = jPlace.getString("reference");

        place.put("description", description);
        place.put("_id", id);
        place.put("reference", reference);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return place;
}
}
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: input = input.replaceAll(" ","%20") is not necessary since the URLEncoder does it already.

Comment: I guess you a not using the PlaceJSONParser correctly. Where can I see it's source code or usage instructions?

Comment: @dev.bmax Thanks for reply I have update the question with the placejson code please check and let me know

Comment: It seems to work properly. The problem is in AutoCompleteTextView. Try my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your Parser task with this:

```
        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        String[] from = new String[] {"description"};
        int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, result,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);
        atvPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);
        atvPlaces.performValidation();
        atvPlaces.showDropDown();
    }
}
```

It forces the AutoCompleteTextView to update the suggestions.

Comment: Dev.bmax there is an small bug is that. When I click on the suggested name of the list it should hide but right now It is not. could you help me in that

Comment: This should be a separate question :)

Comment: dev.bamx It will be very helpful for me please can you help here only for this problem

Comment: In onPostExecute() right after atvPlaces.setAdapter(adapter); add this snippet:             
atvPlaces.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    atvPlaces.setText(result.get(position).get("description"));
                    atvPlaces.dismissDropDown();
                }
            });

Comment: I have try this but did not help me!

Comment: dev.bmax I have post a new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072748/how-to-use-dismissdropdown-in-simpleadapter-listview-in-android   Please help